# Nested UI-Route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am playing with nested view from ui-route, but when I try to access a nested template I get an error. My state:

```
$stateProvider.state('invoice',{
            url: '/invoice',
            views: {
                '@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/invoice.pocketbits.html'
                },
                'list@invoice': {
                templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/database.pocketbits.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

**localhost/#/invoice** works fine but when I try to click "ui-sref="list" from inside I get:

> Error: Could not resolve 'list' from state 'invoice' at
>   Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3141)

Although my list template is inside the invoice.

Comment: What is `list@invoice`? I believe it expects a string.

Comment: Also are you sure the `ui-view` tags are included correctly in the HTML? eg `<div ui-view="viewA"></div><div ui-view="viewB"></div>`

Comment: @TonyBarnes it is another view, I have a button and I want to go to another view inside the "/invoice" state.

I tried, list@, list and nothing seems to work.

according to ui-rotue wiki: Absolute Targeting using '@'  Targets any view within this state or an ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the string you give to ui-sref should refer to a state name.

I mean actually you try to go to a state `list` that you didn't declared.

```
 $stateProvider.state('invoice',{
        url: '/invoice',
        views: {
            '@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/invoice.pocketbits.html'
            },
            'list@invoice': {
            templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/database.pocketbits.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

This state is called "invoice" and have two static nestedview `@` and `list@invoice`

You actually can't go to `list` state.

You may want something like that :

```
 $stateProvider.state('invoice',{
        url: '/invoice',
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/invoice.pocketbits.html'
    });

 $stateProvider.state('invoice.list',{
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/database.pocketbits.html'
    });
```

To be clear. In you index.html you have a `ui-view`.
When you do to state invoice you will replace this ui-view with the template from the invoice state. Your invoice state template will have a `ui-view` inside. When you go to state `invoice.list` you'll add the `invoice.list` template into this `ui-view`.

### EDIT :

**According to your comment this is the usecase you're looking at.**

If you want to have two separate view (ie : when you switch from `invoice` to `list` you'll replace the content of the index.html ui-view) you should do this like this :

```
$stateProvider.state('invoice',{
        url: '/invoice',
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/invoice.pocketbits.html'
    });

 $stateProvider.state('list',{
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.v01/paths/database.pocketbits.html'
    });
```

Hope it helped. If you provide more information on what you try to achieve i could add an exemple of your case and make it working on plunker.

Comment: @Okazri, thanks a lot very well explained. I totally got it. I wanted to organize the states but I forgot that doing that I would have to a static ui-view instead of links. Btw I fixed and it works fine, thanks again!